# Simplificando um Array - PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho um array multidimensional onde os dados encontram-se da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Brasil
                    [1] => Franca
                    [2] => Italia
                    [3] => China
                )

        )

)
```

Gostaria de um método/função que  simplificasse o array para apenas um nível, independente do número de níveis, de forma que os dados fiquem assim:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Brasil
     [1] => Franca
     [2] => Italia
     [3] => China
)
```

Comment: Se o seu array nesse formato sempre, pode usar isso
https://ideone.com/WLw7ma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar funções da classe [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), exemplo:

```
$a = array(array(array("Brasil","Franca","Italia","China")));
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
$novo = array();
foreach($it as $v) {
  $novo[] = $v;
}
print_r($novo);
```

**[Ideone](https://ideone.com/jY6cdH)**

Comment: Ótima resposta. Agora é só criar uma função. Preciso estudar mais os iterators, ajudam muito.

Comment: só fazendo isso já resolveria: `$values = array_values($array[0][0]);`

Comment: @IvanFerrer para este exemplo sim, mais se o array tivesse mais uma ou menos uma dimensão não, ele quer algo que simplifique o array independente da dimensão.

Answer (score 3):

Faça assim:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        array(
            'Brasil',
            'França',
            'Italia',
            'China'
        ),
    ),
);

$new_array = array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', array());
$new_array = array_reduce($new_array, 'array_merge', array());

echo '<pre>', print_r($new_array), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Brasil
    [1] => França
    [2] => Italia
    [3] => China
)
1
```

Ou simplificando mais um pouco, só uma linha:

```
$new_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$foo = array(array(0 => 'Brasil', 1 => 'Franca', 2 => 'Italia'),
    array(0 => 'USA', 1 => 'Russia', 2 => 'China'));

var_dump(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $foo));
```

**Saída:**

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Brasil' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Franca' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Italia' (length=6)
  3 => string 'USA'    (length=3)
  4 => string 'Russia' (length=6)
  5 => string 'China'  (length=5)
```